# How do I declare an object as a part of my class?

Tags: c++, class, oop

For the past couple weekends I have been working on a game. Some of you may have seen code snippets in other questions. I call it Magick.

In Magick, the spells are controlled by the class `Spell` it looks like this:

```
class Spell { 
    public:
        int damage;
        magicTypes type;
        int manaCost;
    };
```

Where `magicTypes` is an `enum class`. However, when I run this in my code:

```
Spell fireball; 
fireball.damage = 50;
fireball.type = fire; 
fireball.manaCost = 50;
```

I get this error:

```
magick1.cpp:117:1: error: ‘fireball’ does not name a type
```

I get this error on every instance of using the `fireball` spell.

This class looks identical to the set up of my other classes and they work and I cant figure out for the life of me why this one does not.

The enum definition looks like this:

```
enum class magicTypes { 
    fire,
    water,
    earth,
    air,
    dark,
    light
};
```

Comment: Not enough information. Did you forget to include the declaration?

Comment: Just edited my answer to include enum definition

Comment: My crystal ball thinks you wrote that at file scope, outside any function.

Comment: The fact that you edited your 'answer to include enum definition' does not mean that the definition is correctly defined in the translation unit that uses it.

Comment: Please provide use with a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem. Unless nobody is able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am floored by my own stupidity, Your crystal ball is very, very correct.

Answer (score 1):

For enum class you should specify the class name:

```
 fireball.type = magicTypes::fire;
```

If you want to cast as int you can do:

```
int i = static_cast<int>(magicTypes::fire);
```